# Why can't I see the navigation back button on the iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a beginner in iOS development. I have a problem when I move the screen. I clicked the button on the story board, then drag it with the right mouse, and then clicked on the view controller that I wanted to move. However, the navigation back button is not visible when the button is pressed. What's the reason?

**Main.storyboard**

[image: storyboard]

[image: storyboard]

**Cell phone**

[image]

Move when the lower right yellow button is pressed.

Move when the lower right yellow button is pressed. My right button is not 'Bar Button Item' but just a button. The reason is that 'Bar Button' is not what I want.

************************ Edited Start ************************************
[image: story]

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goAgreeScreen" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goAgreeScreen", sender: self) // get Error

        } else if segue.identifier == "otherScreen" {

        }
    }
```

Error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee5677ff8)`

************************ Edited end ************************************

*******************Edited Two *******************************************
[image: my board]

**Move Main Screen Button**

```swift
   @IBAction func Onclick(_ sender: Any) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
            if response {
                print(response , ": granted")
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
                { (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        print(granted, ": is granted")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                    } else {
                        print(granted, ": is not granted")
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print(response , ": not granted")
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                // Request permission to display alerts and play sounds.
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
                { (granted, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        if granted == true {
                             print(granted, ": is granted")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                        }
                        else {
                            print(granted, ": is not granted")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.moveScreen()}
                        }
                    } else {
                        print(error as Any)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*******************Edited Two end *****************************************

Comment: Did you see the "Main" heading on your cellphone when you were on the screen with the yellow button? If not, it's possible that you accessed the viewController without it being embedded in the navigationController

Comment: Yes. I can't even see Maine. What do you mean adding it to the navigation controller?  How can I add it?

Comment: Depends on how you are showing the first page. If you are doing it via storyboards, click on the navigation controller and tick "Is initial view controller", and an arrow will appear beside the nav controller. Then when you open the app it should be inside the navigation controller and you will see the "Main" heading and the back button.

Comment: @Daniel As you can see from the pictures on my storyboard, it's connected to the screen Could you look at my edited question?

Comment: Ansersion's answer below is a good reference; if you review that you'll see what needs to be done. You shouldn't put the performSegue command inside the prepare(for segue) function, that's probably what's causing the error (and you don't need to performSegue if you're using storyboards). Also not quite sure what you mean by "it's connected to the screen"?

Comment: Um....@Daniel As you can see from my question, I have already carried out the contents of @Ansession's material. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Daniel The meaning of "it's connected to the screen" is to connect the screen through a right click => drag, just like my storyboard picture. So the Back button is displayed on the story board.

Comment: @Daniel  Could you look at my edited question?

Comment: Okay, from the second picture, it seems that the Main screen is embedded into the nav controller. So how are you moving from your initial screen to the Main screen? Is it via button press via storyboard, or are you using the performSegue that you did before?

Comment: @Daniel  Not checked. So it worked after checking. But as you can see from the picture of my recently edited question, there is a start screen on top of the "Navigation Controller." So if I check the navigation controller, I can't see the start screen.

Comment: @Danie Moving from the start screen will bring up the storyboard and move it to the main screen. 'self.present(mainViewScreen!, animated: true, completion: nil)'

Comment: That's the problem. Using self.present means the mainViewScreen is presented, and the navController is not (and thus the navigation bar will not be shown). It is simpler to move between view controllers using storyboard.

Comment: If you look at the QuickStart example under the heading "To configure the Add button in the meal detail scene" and follow that closely, you can segue using storyboard. You can do the same thing from your yellow button - it doesn't have to be a barbuttonitem. There are other ways, but harder to explain quickly. Good luck!

Comment: @Danie I added a function to the question by pressing a button to go to the main screen. How do I view the navigation headers?

Comment: @Danie ok it worked Thanks you so mush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you presenting the ViewController programmatically? It seems that the navigation bar is not shown.
Maybe you have to present if in a IBAction. Create it connecting a button. Set the identifier to the segue (on the Storyboard) and call it with:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: Do you mean you have to do an event when you press the button?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't need any code for your situation. Here is a Quick-Start example from Apple which is very clear.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1

Comment: As you can see from the pictures on my storyboard, it's connected to the screen

Comment: But I don't see the Main title, I don't see the Back button.